# WPF Dispatcher.Run throws null exception on Win 7 64

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-7-x64

I have the following code to create a new UI thread on a .NET 3.5 application.

```
  private void OnCreateNewWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var rect = this.RestoreBounds;
            double l = rect.Left;
            double wth = rect.Width;
            double t = rect.Top;
            double ht = rect.Height;
            var progressThread = new Thread(() =>
            {

                progressWindow = new ProgressWindow(Visibility.Collapsed) { Height = 50, Width = 50 };
                progressWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
                progressWindow.Left = l + (wth - progressWindow.Width) / 2;
                progressWindow.Top = t - 35 + (ht - progressWindow.Height) / 2;

                progressWindow.Show();
                progressWindow.Activate();
                Dispatcher.Run();
            });

            progressThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            progressThread.Start();
        }
```

Crash is demonstrated here:  [image]

This works perfectly on 32 bit versions of Windows.  The first time I run this program upon PC reboot on 64 bit Windows 7, I get a null exception, if run via Visual Studio or an application crash outside of Visual Studio.

Exception details is dry:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
```

Stack trace is given below:

```
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.DestroyWindow(object args) + 0xfc bytes    
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.Dispose(bool disposing, bool isHwndBeingDestroyed) + 0xce bytes    
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.Dispose() + 0x15 bytes 
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContextNotificationWindow.DisposeNotificationWindow() + 0x22 bytes   
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Dispose() + 0xba bytes   
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ShutdownImplInSecurityContext(object state) + 0x47 bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(object userData) + 0x178 bytes    
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x62 bytes    
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ShutdownImpl() + 0x87 bytes 
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) + 0x121 bytes 
>   EMS.Controls.Dictionary.dll!EMS.Controls.Dictionary.Views.AuthenticateWindow.OnCreateNewWindow.AnonymousMethod() Line 56 + 0x5 bytes    C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x9b bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x4d bytes
```

If I continue to run the program again, I get a message from the Program Compatibility Assitant, indicating that some compatibility settings have been applied.  Next time I run the program I no longer get this exception.  Anyone experienced this?

Comment: Edited post with stack trace.  It is very dry.  Thanks.

Comment: Click right mouse button on [External Code] and select "Show External Code"

Comment: Marak, post has been edited with external stack trace.  thanks.

Comment: @e28Makaveli: what does your `App.xaml.cs`/`App.xaml` look like? It seems like you're using some non-standard ways of opening up new windows. The error message is clear that `this.Dispatcher` is `null`, but it isn't terribly obvious as to why.

Comment: @sixlettervariables, yes, I create circular progress bars using the code above when user is waiting for response to login, as well as when the application is loading.  How do I add my app.xaml and app.cs.caml?  Together, they are greater than 300 characters.  All I do in App.cs.xaml is set some threadpool params, hook to appdomain's unhandled exception and show a splash screen.  I also have this line :    new HwndSource(new HwndSourceParameters()); to prevent leak caused by progress bar.  My App.xaml is standard.  Nothing in there.

Answer (score 1):

This problem had to do with the application launch sequence.  The progress window was being created on a separate UI thread so that authentication to a webservice, required for application launch, could be done on the UI thread.  It appears as though invoking webservice methods on the main UI thread is problematic based on this [thread on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/fb82a762-8703-4eee-9858-2a276966f96c) .

Luckily, this is the only place in the application where webservice methods are invoked synchronously on the UI thread.

After making changes to launch the progress window on the main UI thread while authentication to the webservice on a background thread, problem has not occurred so far.
Interesting that this problem did not occur on other versions of Windows including Windows 7 x32.